# Add an item in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte

I am using tufte-book document class.
I would like to add a part at the end of the document which is neither a chapter nor a section. How can I do for making this part visible in the tableofcontents?

Answer (score 117):

## Remarks

You may use the `\addcontentsline` command. The syntax is defined as follows

```
\addcontentsline{TABLE}{LEVEL}{TITLE}
```

- `TABLE` stands for the type of list, where you want to add the item, possible are:

  - `toc`: Table of contents
  - `lof`: List of figures
  - `lot`: List of tables
- `LEVEL` will be the level at which the line will appear in the list. Possible are:

  - For `toc`: `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`
  - For `lof`: `figure`
  - For `lot`: `table`
- `TITLE` is your heading.

For example

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

will add *Appendix* to your table of contents, but will **NOT** typeset the heading within the document. You need to use `\chapter*{Appendix}` for this.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Historical Overview}
\chapter{Implementation}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\section*{The Mathematical Background}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{The Mathematical Background}
\subsection*{Proofs}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Proofs}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image: Tufte]

Comment: But in this case, "Appendix" is not enumerated within the toc. Any way to get this working, too?

Comment: @Coxa Just replace `\chapter*{...}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}` by `\chapter{...}` to restore the default behaviour.

Comment: Another immediate solution from TeX StackExchange! Many thanks for the contributions of everyone to this wonderful resource.

Comment: `\phantomsection` might be needed if the hyperref doesn't work properly...