# Having a "\part" without roman numeral in front in the ToC

Tags: formatting

I have a document in the `book` format. It is subdivided into different parts, which appear in the table of contents as "I. part 1", "II. part 1" and so on. At some point, I have the appendices, and I would like it to appear in the table of contents just as "Appendices", without the roman numeral. I tried using `\part*{Appendices}`, but if I do that the entry completely disappear from the table of contents.  I guess I could just force the entry in the table of contents (as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119719/add-an-item-in-the-table-of-contents)), but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it. Any ideas or advice?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents

    \part{Body}

    Text

    \part*{Appendices}

    Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: \appendixpage and \addappheadtotoc from the appendix package both att "Appendices" to the TOC at a part level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any additional packages you can use `\addcontentsline` for that. Just make sure it is used on the correct page (`\cleardoublepage`).

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents

    \part{Body}

    Text

    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}%
    \part*{Appendices}

    Text

\end{document}
```

If you're using KOMA-script the solution would be way more elegant: KOMA defines a command `\addpart` for exactly that purpose:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents

    \part{Body}

    Text

    \addpart{Appendices}

    Text

\end{document}
```